# Specify order of (T)SQL execution

Tags: sql, t-sql, where-clause

I have seen similar questions asked elsewhere on this site, but more in the context of optimization.

I am having an issue with the order of execution of the conditions in a WHERE clause.  I have a field which stores codes, most of which are numeric but some of which contain non-numeric characters.  I need to do some operations on the numeric codes which will cause errors if attempted on non-numeric strings.  I am trying to do something like

```
WHERE isnumeric(code) = 1
AND CAST(code AS integer) % 2 = 1
```

Is there any way to make sure that the isnumeric() executes first?  If it doesn't, I get an error...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will almost certainly need to use a `CASE` expression here, because SQL does not allow you to define an order of evaluation.

Comment: The problem here is that SQL standard lacks [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Which is good in fact, but that's only my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

The only place order of evaluation is guaranteed is `CASE`

```
WHERE 
     CASE WHEN isnumeric(code) = 1 
          THEN CAST(code AS integer) % 2 
END = 1
```

Also just because it passes the `isnumeric` test doesn't guarantee that it will successfully `cast` to an integer.

```
 SELECT ISNUMERIC('$') /*Returns 1*/

 SELECT CAST('$' AS INTEGER) /*Fails*/
```

Depending upon your needs you may find [these alternatives](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber) preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do it using LIKE?:

```
Where Code Not Like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Btw, either using my solution or using IsNumeric, there are some edge cases which might lead one to using a UDF such as `1,234,567` where IsNumeric will return 1 but Cast will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a CASE statement to say something like:

```
WHERE 
CASE WHEN isnumeric(code) = 1 
THEN CAST(code AS int) % 2 = 1 
ELSE /* What ever else if not numeric */ END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a `case` statement in the `select` clause, then limit by the value in an outer `select`

```
select * from (    
    select
    case when isNum = 1 then CAST(code AS integer) % 2 else 0 end as castVal
    from (
       select
       Case when isnumeric(code) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as isNum
       from table) t
) t2
where castval = 1
```